# After updating to TeXLive 2021, the environment \AtBeginDocument errors out in beamer

Tags: beamer, tex-core, animate

I used to use TexLive 2019 on my Mac which has been recently updated to Catalina. I decided to update TeXLive as well. So I downloaded and installed TexLive 2021.
After this update, some of my slides created using beamer and a custom-defined style `.sty` cannot be compiled due to error saying that `Missing number, treated as zero`.
After a tedious debugging, I narrowed down the problem into a problem using `\AtBeginDocument` environment in the `.sty` file. (This error can also be reproduced if `\AtBeginDocument` environment is also put in the preamble of the `.tex` file.

Below are example `.sty` and `.tex` files that can be used to reproduce the error.

1. Style file (`reproduce_bug_style.sty`):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{my_test1}
  [2019/10/02 my_test1]

% Berlin theme
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme[compress]{Berlin}}

% Setup first frame
\AtBeginDocument{
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[ball unnumbered]
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{}
    \begin{center}
      {\large \textbf{\arabic{1}.~\insertsubtitle}}
    \end{center}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{frame}
}

\endinput
```

2. TeX file (`reproduce_bug.tex`):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{reproduce_bug_style}

%%% Title Page
% short title (course number) and title (course title) appear at the top of the first slide
\title[Short Title]{Title} 
% short subtitle appears in the footer on the left hand side
\subtitle[Short Subtitle]{Subtitle} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

One way of resolving the issue is to use the environment `\AtBeginSection[]`. However, I'm wondering what has changed in the release 2021 compared to 2019 that results in this error (`Missing number, treated as zero`). Any insight is very much obliged.

**Main Problem**
I have a custom `.sty` file for typesetting my lecture slides. In that, I have defined a counter named `subnum` counting subjects. After updating to TexLive 2021 on my mac with Catalina OS, I keep receiving two errors going as below:

1. `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \g_pbs_ocgbase_loaded_bool`
2. `Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>`

I thought that my narrowdown to the problem mentioned above is the culprit. It seems that this may not be the main cause of the error. However, the workaround still works in this case.

The first error is due to the `animate` package.

Any insight or better solution is very much obliged.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I don't see that this could ever have worked: `\arabic{1}` is an error as `1` isn't a counter (certainly not in the MWE).

Comment: The order how code in \AtBeginDocument is executed has slightly changed. Perhaps you have somewhere else a \newcounter{1} which is now executed too late. But you shouldn't do typesetting in \AtBeginDocument anyway. That is the wrong hook for this. Use \AddToHook{begindocument/end}{...} for your code instead.

Comment: @JosephWright, you are absolutely right. To reproduce the error message, I deleted the `\section{Introduction}` in the .`tex` file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Thanks for the info. I will talk about my main problem below.

Comment: I think that the issue has to do with the latest changes in the package `animate`. Commenting out this package solves my issue without any workaround. But I'm curious why the `animate` package produces an error `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \g_pbs_ocgbase_loaded_bool`. Any insight is very much appreciated.

Comment: I fixed this in `pdfbase.sty` which is part of pkg media9 and loaded by animate. Thank you for reporting.

Comment: OP submitted a related [bug report](https://gitlab.com/agrahn/animate/-/issues/15) which was addressed and fixed by updating `pdfbase.sty` (pkg media9). Therefore, I’m voting to close this question.